# Can't see the betterlog output in my spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand that it writes to the sheet when the log reaches 50,000 lines.  But my script doesn't generate 50,000 lines of log, and I need to see the log once the script's finished.  Is there a way to flush the log to the sheet once it finishes.  Or reduce the threshold below 50k?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, and don't I feel stupid.  I didn't notice Betterlog created another sheet/tab named Log in the sheet, and it's logging to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Logger.getLog()` to get the entire text at once.

But you will have to split it in smaller parts, because each cell of the sheet has a limit of 50k characters.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#getLog%28%29

Comment: Logger.getlog() appears to not work any longer once Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet has been executed.  "TypeError: Cannot find function getLog in object.